# Spring @ResponseBody json last in double braces

Tags: json, spring

I return to Map Object  @ResponseBody to Json

Then last in braces to double

```
....ocateCode":"1000"}],"errMsg":"","success":true}}
```

Then Ajax not loaded

Why Added Last in double braces

Comment: Can you provide the full JSON?

Answer (score 0):

This: `{"answer": {"value": 42}}` is valid JSON.

If you have a model that looks something like this:

```
class MyObject{
    MyOtherObject otherObject;
}
```

Then this could, after serialization,have the double curly braces at the end.

Try debugging your AJAX call and see whether or not the fault lies somewhere else.